# Error in compilation : undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformInfo@20'

Tags: windows, qt, opencl

I'm such a newby concerning OpenCL programming, and I want to run a simple program which is in "OpenCL Parallel Programming Development Cookbook". 
In fact, I want to query OpenCl platforms by this simple prog:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

void displayPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id id,
                     cl_platform_info param_name,
                     const char* paramNameAsStr) {
    cl_int error = 0;
    size_t paramSize = 0;
    error = clGetPlatformInfo( id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize );
    char* moreInfo = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * paramSize);
    error = clGetPlatformInfo( id, param_name, paramSize,moreInfo, NULL );
    if (error != CL_SUCCESS ) {
        perror("Unable to find any OpenCL platform information");
           return;
    }
    printf("%s: %s\n", paramNameAsStr, moreInfo);
}
int main() {
    /* OpenCL 1.2 data structures */
    cl_platform_id* platforms;
    /* OpenCL 1.1 scalar data types */
    cl_uint numOfPlatforms;
    cl_int error;
    /*
Get the number of platforms
Remember that for each vendor's SDK installed on the
Computer, the number of available platform also
*/
    error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numOfPlatforms);
    if(error < 0) {
        perror("Unable to find any OpenCL platforms");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Allocate memory for the number of installed platforms.
    // alloca(...) occupies some stack space but is
    // automatically freed on return
    platforms = (cl_platform_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id)
                                     * numOfPlatforms);
    printf("Number of OpenCL platforms found: %d\n",
       numOfPlatforms);
    // We invoke the API 'clPlatformInfo' twice for each
    // parameter we're trying to extract
    // and we use the return value to create temporary data
    // structures (on the stack) to store
    // the returned information on the second invocation.
    for(cl_uint i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; ++i) {
        displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i],
                         CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE,
                         "CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE" );
        displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i],
                         CL_PLATFORM_VERSION,
                         "CL_PLATFORM_VERSION" );
        displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i],
                         CL_PLATFORM_NAME,
                         "CL_PLATFORM_NAME" );
        displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i],
                         CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,
                         "CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR" );
        displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i],
                         CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,
                         "CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Qt Creator, and my pc's config concerning video is : NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 635M & Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 under Windows 8.1

My .pro file is :

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

INCLUDEPATH += \
    $$quote(C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.5/include)

LIBS += \
    $$quote(C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.5/lib/x64/OpenCL.lib)
```

Because of spaces in file path. So, my question is : Why, when i'm compiling my project, does the problem "undefined reference to `clGetPlatformInfo@20'" appear? There's 2 others errors (one which exactly the same, the other is "undefined reference to`clGetPlatformIDs@12'")

I search on the web for a lot of days and I can't find the answer (these prob has answer but on Linux or on Mac..)

Thanks in advance !

Mathieu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build 32-bit application, while linking with 64-bit version of OpenCL.lib:

> C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.5/lib/**x64**/OpenCL.lib

So, either build application in 64-bit mode, or fix the path to point to 32-bit version of OpenCL.lib.